# Kotlin load a collection of a class from a file?

Tags: c++, kotlin, io

In C++ I can load a collection of a class from a file using a friend [operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) overload:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is_a, College& college_a) {
    return is_a >> college_a.id_,
        is_a.get(),
        std::getline(is_a,college_a.name_);
}

std::set<College> colleges {};
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<College> {std::cin},
    std::istream_iterator<College> {},
    std::inserter(colleges, colleges.begin()));
```

from a file like this:

```
0707 Rowan Technical College
0980 University of Saskatchewan
1058 Belmont University
1072 Belmont Technical College
```

How would this be done with Kotlin?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to parse a file and split the lines in Kotlin / Java. 
The next example uses a Regex to split the line into an id and the name for the college:

```
data class College(val id: String, val name: String)

val colleges = File("input.txt").useLines { lines ->
    val regex = Regex("(\\d+) (.+)")
    lines.mapNotNull { line ->
        regex.matchEntire(line)?.let {
            College(it.groupValues[1], it.groupValues[2])
        }
    }.toList()
}
```

If you need to read from the standard input, then replace the third line with:

```
val colleges = InputStreamReader(System.`in`).useLines { lines ->
```

**Update: Hide details**

There is no general way to parse text files into object in Java / Kotlin. For XML and Json files exists some standard APIs and you can register Serializer/Deserializer for each type.

If you need such an abstraction for simple line oriented text files you have to build it yourself. The next examples may give you an idea:

```
fun <T : Any> File.parseLines(lineParser: (String) -> T?): List<T> =
    useLines { it.mapNotNull(lineParser).toList() }
```

The function extend the `File` class with a `parseLines` method.

The implementation of the line parser for class `College` would be like this:

```
val collegeLineParser: (String) -> College? = { line ->
    val regex = Regex("(\\d+) (.+)")
    regex.matchEntire(line)?.let {
        College(it.groupValues[1], it.groupValues[2])
    }
}
```

Or if you like to cache the `RegEx`:

```
val collegeLineParserCachedRegex = object : (String) -> College? {
    val regex = Regex("(\\d+) (.+)")
    override fun invoke(line: String): College? =
        regex.matchEntire(line)?.let {
            College(it.groupValues[1], it.groupValues[2])
        }
}
```

Now you can invoke the method `parseLines` on a `File`:

```
val colleges = File("input.txt").parseLines(collegeLineParser)
```

**Update: Registry for parsers**

If you do not like to provide the `lineParser` for every call, you can create a registry:

```
object LineParserRegistry {
    val parsers = ConcurrentHashMap<KClass<*>, (String) -> Any?>()

    inline fun <reified T> register(noinline parser : (String) -> T?) {
        parsers[T::class] = parser
    }

    inline fun <reified T> get(): (String) -> T? {
        // force companion initializer
        Class.forName(T::class.java.name)
        return parsers[T::class] as (String) -> T??
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> File.parseLines(): List<T> =
    useLines { it.mapNotNull(LineParserRegistry.get<T>()).toList() }
```

If you like to register the parsers automatically you need to add an companion object with an `init` method:

```
data class College(val id: String, val name: String) {
    companion object {
        init {
            val collegeLineParser: (String) -> College? = { line ->
                val regex = Regex("(\\d+) (.+)")
                regex.matchEntire(line)?.let {
                    College(it.groupValues[1], it.groupValues[2])
                }
            }
            LineParserRegistry.register(collegeLineParser)
        }
    }
}
```

This `init` method is invoked the first time the `College` class is used. But reflection does not count, therefore we had to add `Class.forName(T::class.java.name)` into the `get` method of the registry. This call forces the initialization of the companion object.

Now you can call the parser without any preparations:

```
val colleges = File("input.txt").parseLines<College>()
```

Comment: How about the hiding of the regex and formatting details from the user of College?

Comment: I just extend my answer with some ideas to hide the details.

Comment: The 'Registry for parsers' addresses the question that popped up.  Can the .register() be hidden in the class?

Comment: I am trying it. I have describe the results I get in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57015559/eclipse-kotlin-identifying-just-some-needed-imports .
Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you missed the "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib" and maybe the "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect" in your dependencies.