# Eclipse/Kotlin identifying just some needed imports

Tags: eclipse, kotlin, import

I followed the instructions for [Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started-eclipse.html). A Hello World test works fine. I then did a File>New>Kotlin File.

```
package so2
object LineParserRegistry {
    val parsers = ConcurrentHashMap<KClass<*>, (String) -> Any?>()
    inline fun <reified T> register(noinline parser : (String) -> T?) {
        parsers[T::class] = parser
    }
    inline fun <reified T> get(): (String) -> T? {
        // force companion initializer
        Class.forName(T::class.java.name)
        return parsers[T::class] as (String) -> T??
    }
}
data class College(val id: String, val name: String) {
    companion object {
        init {
            val collegeLineParser: (String) -> College? = { line ->
                val regex = Regex("(\\d+) (.+)")
                regex.matchEntire(line)?.let {
                    College(it.groupValues[1], it.groupValues[2])
                }
            }
            LineParserRegistry.register(collegeLineParser)
        }
    }
}
inline fun <reified T : Any> File.parseLines(): List<T> =
    useLines { it.mapNotNull(LineParserRegistry.get<T>()).toList() }
fun main(){
    val colleges = File("/home/cwhii/work/input.txt").parseLines<College>()
    println("colleges: $colleges")
    println("OK.")
}
```

Eclipse offered to add these `imports` which I had it do:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import java.io.File
```

When I run it here is the result:

```
No Location
    ERROR: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class kotlin.text.Regex, unresolved supertypes: java.io.Serializable

/home/cwhii/work/sw/kaptcp/src/so/loadClass.kt
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: File (14, 30)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: File (18, 17)
/home/cwhii/work/sw/kaptcp/src/so2/hiddenReg.kt
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: java (2, 8)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: java (4, 8)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: ConcurrentHashMap (6, 19)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: Class (12, 9)
    ERROR: Cannot access class 'java.lang.Class'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies (12, 32)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: name (12, 37)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: File (29, 30)
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: File (32, 20)
```

First how is this resolved? Secondly, why did Eclipse point out the `import` issues but not these others?

Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables
[image: Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables]

I assume that because Eclipse knew enough to suggest `import java.io.File` which is in `import java.io` that `java.io.Serializable` would be in the same place, that it would exist on the system for it to be found. If this is not true where do I locate what is and is not supposed to be here?

Answer (score 3):

Try to set JDK home option on eclipse preferences -> kotlin -> compiler, it has worked for me